# How do I exit a process in terminal without killing it?

Tags: bash, scripts

I created a script to run my react build on port 5555

[image]

and on running it, I get

[image]

I want to quit this process without killing the server.

How can I do it?

Output with `&`

[image]

Comment: How about disowning a process or putting job in background?

Comment: Already answered.

Comment: You could also use my Favorite! `screen` detached.

Comment: @EODCraftStaff how to use it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is sending the current foreground job to the background.
You can simply achieve this by:

suspending the current job. `[CTRL-Z]` then,

send the job to the background. `bg`

To see if the the job has being successfully send to the background, run:
`jobs`

Another method would be starting the process in the background. To achieve this, include an ampersand *"&"* at the end of the command. Example;
if my script name is process1, I will run it using `./process1 &`.

Success!

Comment: can you tell me how can I add that [CTRL-Z] in my script...and I updated the question with the output of the command with &

Comment: @preIdiot That's the STDOUT you got. If you don't want to see that, you can redirect to `/dev/null`. Try running `homepage &>/dev/null`.

Comment: Just add ampersand "&" after the word build

Comment: yeah...this is what I want, thanks!! @Kulfy